# Video.js and Ima Sdk

Tags: javascript, php, sdk, ads, video.js

When i visit my video url:

```
https://www.domain.com/watch?v=videoid
```

the ads don't work, but when i visit

```
https://www.domain.com/watch
```

The ads do work so its really strange.
Even when i change te filename to something else lets say watchh.php and visit the second url the ads won't work

Does someone know whats going on? I'm using video.js and ima sdk from google for TrueView ads

i'm using this video.js plugin:

http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.nl/2014/08/introducing-ima-sdk-plugin-for-videojs.html

Comment: Without a sample code it's difficult to help you, btw you should add something like `player.ima.addEventListener( google.ima.AdEvent.AD_ERROR, callback )` and in the callback log in console potential errors from the request.